# Can a provided type be used in a quotation - Do TypeProvider calls appear in ReflectedDefinition functions?

Tags: f#, type-providers, quotations

I'd like to generate a type with static functions, that I can then use in functions that become quotations using the **ReflectedDefinition** attribute. It seems to me a convenient way of translating something into FSharp types, using FSharp to compose the domain of functions and types, and spit the composed code back into its native form, having received the benefit of type checking, VS intellisense, higher order functions, etc. To try and get started I have this type provider, largely *copy->pasted* from various articles

```
[<TypeProvider>]
type CSoundTypeProvider(config: TypeProviderConfig) as this = 

    inherit ProvidedTypes.TypeProviderForNamespaces()

    let namespaceName = "TestNamespace"
    let thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

//    config.

    let intType = typeof<int>
    let providedParam = ProvidedTypes.ProvidedParameter("prm", intType)
    let providedFunction = ProvidedTypes.ProvidedMethod("TestMethod", [providedParam], intType, IsStaticMethod=true
                                    , InvokeCode = fun args -> 
                                                  // The 'args' parameter represents expressions that give us access to the 
                                                  // instance on which the method is invoked and other parameters (if there are more)
                                                  let instance = args.[0]
                                                  // Now we can return quotation representing a call to MethodInfo 'p' with 'instance'
                                                  instance)
    let csoundProvidedWrapper = ProvidedTypes.ProvidedTypeDefinition(thisAssembly, namespaceName, "TestType", None)
    do csoundProvidedWrapper.AddMember(providedFunction)
    do this.AddNamespace(namespaceName, [csoundProvidedWrapper])
```

And testing it with this reflected definition:

```
[<ReflectedDefinition>]
let myfn i j =
    let k = i * j
    let x = k + 2
    let f = TestNamespace.TestType.TestMethod k
    let ret = f + 2
    ret
```

I'm parsing the reflected definition like this:

```
<@ myfn @> |> println
```

**println** is a function (copied from another article) that has many of the active patterns for parsing quotations like ***Patterns.Call(None, DerivedPatterns.MethodWithReflectedDefinition(n), expList)***, which gets me an experssion tree of all of the code, ***except*** for the provided static method. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, what's the active pattern I've likely missed from my println function here:

```
let println expr =
    let rec print expr = match expr with
        | Patterns.Application(expr1, expr2) ->
            // Function application.
            print expr1
            printf " "
            print expr2
        | Patterns.Call(None, DerivedPatterns.MethodWithReflectedDefinition(n), expList) ->
            print n
        | Patterns.Call(exprOpt, methodInfo, exprList) ->
            // Method or module function call.
            match exprOpt with
            | Some expr -> print expr
            | None -> printf "%s" methodInfo.DeclaringType.Name
            printf ".%s(" methodInfo.Name
            if (exprList.IsEmpty) then printf ")" else
            print exprList.Head
            for expr in exprList.Tail do
                printf ","
                print expr
            printf ")"
        | DerivedPatterns.Int32(n) ->
            printf "%d" n
        | Patterns.Lambda(param, body) ->
            // Lambda expression.
            printf "fun (%s:%s) -> " param.Name (param.Type.ToString())
            print body
        | Patterns.Let(var, expr1, expr2) ->
            // Let binding.
            if (var.IsMutable) then
                printf "let mutable %s = " var.Name
            else
                printf "let %s = " var.Name
            print expr1
            printf " in "
            print expr2
        | Patterns.PropertyGet(_, propOrValInfo, _) ->
            printf "%s" propOrValInfo.Name
        | DerivedPatterns.String(str) ->
            printf "%s" str
        | Patterns.Value(value, typ) ->
            printf "%s" (value.ToString())
        | Patterns.Var(var) ->
            printf "%s" var.Name
        | _ -> printf "%s" (expr.ToString())
    print expr
```

If I can't do this, what approach would you recommend for generating FSharp definitions that I can use in quotations? I've largely been influenced by the FunScript project, but hoping to avoid the step where it seems each Typescript definition has to get compiled into a seperate DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the type provider demos out there use *erased type providers* which do not produce actual .NET types. When you use an erased type provider, the generated methods are *erased* and replaced with the code you provided in the method's `InvokeCode`.

Let's say you have a method `Foo` that erases to `someFunc` with `"Foo"` as an argument:

```
myObj.Foo()   ~>    someFunc(myObj, "Foo")
```

In quotations, you will also see the erased version (both in direct `<@ .. @>` and in `ReflectedDefinition`):

```
<@ myObj.Foo() @>  ~> <@ someFunc(myObj, "Foo") @>
```

The way FunScript type provider works is that it generates some dummy code that contains the function name so that it can then generate the corresponding JavaScript. Say you have:

```
<@ win.Alert(arg) @> ~> <@ invokeFunction("alert", win, arg) @>
```

To do the same sort of thing, you'll need to define a function like `invokeFunction` and to generate appropriate `InvokeCode`. Then you can look for calls to `invokeFunction` in the generated quotation and do whatever special thing you need to do there. It is a bit hard to see what exactly are you trying to do, but this should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain this. I hadn't appreciated that the **InvokeCode** definition was so important. I'm only trying to generate types as deep as the public interface of the Type Provider, hence the dumb code in my example. In the light of this info, perhaps writing a Type Provider is overkill for what I'm really trying to do, which is codegen'ing an interface.